# void include ( include with no return)

Tags: php

```
//include.php  
<?php  
echo 'ABC';  
?>

//buzz.php  
<?php
$a = include('include.php);
echo $a
?>
```

-> Output: ABC1. give me a solution (i know why, needn't explain);

Comment: This is a poorly worded question. What's being asked?

Comment: I want to output abc, not abc1, (bad english)

Comment: So lose the `$a =` and `echo $a` parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output buffering might be what you're looking for:

```
//include.php  
<?php  
echo 'ABC';  
?>

//buzz.php  
<?php
ob_start()
include('include.php'); // Added the closing quote, it's missing in your example
$a = ob_get_clean();

echo $a; // ABC
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you, by `include` ing it, not have to `echo` it because it's already `echo`ed in the source file?

Comment: @seanny94 Indeed, but this was my best guess at what Snoob's real-world problem is.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` will output to the output buffer, so if you call echo once in include.php then you don't need to try to call it again in buzz.php.

`include()` will return `1` if the files exists and `0` if it doesn't so you're code will output `ABC` when include.php is run, then it will print `1` when include('include.php') is called, since the file does exist.

To only print `ABC` follow Mike's advice or the simpler:

```
//include.php  
<?php  
echo 'ABC';  
?>

//buzz.php  
<?php
include('include.php);
?>
```

Finally, you can return from files;

```
//include.php  
<?php  
return 'ABC';  
?>

//buzz.php  
<?php
$a = include('include.php');
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: i want to make template engine for my project, so this isn't i want.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
$a = include('include.php);
```

`include()` will return boolean TRUE if the include succeeded, so $a becomes TRUE, which is cast to a `1` when you output it.

Comment: i knew why, needn't explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `return`

```
//include.php
return 'ABC';

//buzz.php
$data = include('include.php');
echo $data;  // ABC
```